# Android: How To Pass Value on Fragment to Activity Class (Dealing with TabPages)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I would like to know how to pass my values similarly like sessions in C# to Android. Here is my log in Class that is loading my main page.

```
String sEmployeeName = Message.toString();
            String sEmployeeID = UserID;

            Person person = new Person();

            person.setFirstName("Welcome, " + sEmployeeName);
            person.setLastName(UserID);



            Intent intentMain = new Intent(LoginActivity.this ,
                    SwipePageActivity.class);
            intentMain.putExtra("Person", person);
            startActivity(intentMain);
```

Note that my SwipePageActivity.Class is my class to load TabPages. I created a Tab1 class to populate an activity in my first tab. In my Tab1 fragment i have a code like this

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,container,false );
            return rootView;

        }
    }
```

Person.Class code looks like this

```
import  java.io.Serializable;

public class Person implements Serializable {

    String sFirstName;
    String sLastName;

    public void setFirstName(String sFirstName){
        this.sFirstName = sFirstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String sLastName){
        this.sLastName = sLastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return sFirstName;
    }

    public String getLastName()
    {
        return sLastName;
    }

}
```

On my activity_main layout i have a java class coded like this

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Person person = (Person)  getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("Person");

        final Button btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
        //final Button btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);
        final Button btnApprove = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnApprove);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        findViewById(R.id.txtEmployeeID).setVisibility(View.GONE);

        final TextView tvID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEmployeeID);

        TextView tvName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEmployeeName);
        tvName.setText(person.getFirstName());
        tvID.setText(person.getLastName());

        assert btnSearch != null;
        assert btnApprove != null;
        //assert btnLogout != null;
}
```

what i want is to get the value that i pass in Person Class on my Login Class.

Can anyone help me out?

If you need my page adapter code here it is

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch(position) {
            case 0:
                Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
                return  tab1;
            case 1:
                Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();
                return  tab2;
            case 2:
                Tab3 tab3 = new Tab3();
                return  tab3;
        }
        return  null;
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        //return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "APPROVAL";
            case 1:
                return "NONE";
            case 2:
                return "NONE";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the Person object to the Adapter's constructor and then in your getItem method, create Bundle object and save that Person into it (bundle.putParcalable). After that pass that bundle to the fragment(tab1.setArguments(bundle)).

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private Person person;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Person person) {
        super(fm);
        this.person = person;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch(position) {
            case 0:
                Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putParcelable("person", person);
                tab1.setArguments(bundle);
                return  tab1;
            case 1:
                Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();
                return  tab2;
            case 2:
                Tab3 tab3 = new Tab3();
                return  tab3;
        }
        return  null;
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        //return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "APPROVAL";
            case 1:
                return "NONE";
            case 2:
                return "NONE";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

To get the Person object in your fragment create Bundle object and get it from Fragment's arguments(getArguments()). Then get the Person object from the Bundle :

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

    private Person person;

    @Nullable
    @Override

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Bundle bundle = getArguments();
            person = (Person) bundle.getParcelable("person");
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,container,false );
            return rootView;

        }
    }
```

Now you have the Person object in your fragment! :)

Comment: but how can I get the Person values to my MainActivity.Class?

Comment: You have the Person object, so you can get the values from it. 
person.getFirstName();
person.getLastName();

Comment: I don't understand you. You want Person values in your Fragment or in MainActivtiy ?

Comment: in MainActivity.

Comment: then show me where you make Intent to your MainActivity class, cuz you need to pass the Person object into the intent

Comment: Intent intentMain = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SwipePageActivity.class);
            intentMain.putExtra("Person", person);
            startActivity(intentMain);
You make intent to SwipePageActivity! I can't see intent to MainActivity nowhere ...

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear at all, but if I understand, you want to have the info of the "Person" who has logedIn.

I would do it this way:

In Person.class:

```
public class Person implements... {
private static Person currentPerson;

public static Person getCurrentPerson(){
return currentPerson;

public static void setCurrentPerson(Person current){
currentPerson = current;
}
```

When you do Login you set the currentUser with Person.setCurrentPerson()...

When you want to get it you call Person.getCurrentPerson()

When you do logOut you setCurrentPerson to null.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Hi I've edited my question, i've posted my person class.

Comment: @eljon_i3 have you tried my answer? Is it not what you need?